# Отправить пост запрос в андроид приложении

Tags: java, android

Собственно, как отправить пост запрос в андроид приложении по нажатию кнопки, асинхронно, ибо синхронный метод вызывает исключение с основного потока, и получить ответ, перепробовал кучу вариантов, то не компилируется то не отправляет запрос

```
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.loopj.android.http. *;

AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("https://google.com/", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // Initiated the request
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
        // Response failed :(
    }

    @Override
    public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
        // Request was retried
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgress(long bytesWritten, long totalSize) {
        // Progress notification
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // Completed the request (either success or failure)
    }
});
```

Comment: какую библиотеку используете?

Comment: приводите любой пример кода который не работает.

Comment: Retrofit вам в помощь.

Comment: добавил пример в шапку, который не отправляет запрос

Comment: Ну если бы речь шла о Retrofit и Kotlin, то ответ был бы прост. Kotlin coroutine + Retrofit. Есть специальные либы для этого, но думаю, есть что - то в стиле Retrofit + RXJava